# Onbeforeunload - popux box will not display or trigger

Tags: php, javascript, if-statement

I am building a website with user-profiles. I am at the picture part at the moment. When a person upload their image with no problem, the picture will be stored in 4 different folders. One for size 25, 100, 150 and normal size. After this they will be redirected to the same page, with new content. This is the part, where they need to crop their picture. Crop part works great, but I have a problem. When they leave the site without cropping, the pciture they just uploaded is still stored in the folders, and that's not what i want. So i mate some checks with AJAX, and it will unlink the 4 files sotred already. My problem is, that this shall only happen, when they leave the site(onbeforeunload.) 
This works very great in IE, but not in Chrome.(Only two browsers i've tested yet.)

Here is what I'm doing:

```
function unfinished(album,img){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","incl/unfinished.php?a=" + album + "&i=" + img,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

The function above get information from "uncl/unfinished.php" by the query string. And it all works well.

Code on unfinished.php:

```
session_start();
require('../dbconnect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $username= $row['brugernavn'];
}
$album = $_GET['a'];
$img = $_GET['i'];
$sourcex = "../users/".$username."/images/".$album."/x-x/".$img;
$source25 = "../users/".$username."/images/".$album."/25/".$img;
$source100 = "../users/".$username."/images/".$album."/100/".$img;
$source150 = "../users/".$username."/images/".$album."/150/".$img;

if(unlink($sourcex)){

}
if(unlink($source25)){

}
if(unlink($source100)){

}
if(unlink($source150)){

}
echo "Error 908. The picture didn't get cropped, and neither saved. Try again.";
```

The AJAX code and unfinished.php deletes the images withpout any problems. I've tested that already. Now my problem:
I am running the AJAX code by

The code should be running inside this:

```
//function warn(album,img){
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = unfinished(album,img);
  }

  // For Safari
  return unfinished(album,img);

};
//}
```

But when i try to return xmlhttp.responseText, the popup box doesn't popup, and i am not able to see the response.
But if i add "Hello world"(or some text) to the return like **return Helloworld!'';** or **e.returnValue = 'Hello world!';**, instead of the xmlhttp.responseText value, it pops up, and display the message. But it doesn't display the xmlhttp.responseText, because it doesn't run the **unfinished()** function.

any solutions how i can run the AJAX when user leaves page?
If it helps here is the HTML code:

```
if($_POST['where'] == "newalbum"){
$nameonalbum = $_POST['nameonalbum'];
}else{
$nameonalbum = $_POST['existingalbum'];
}
$filenamenew=time().'.gif';
?>
<body onload="warn('<?=$nameonalbum?>','<?=$filenamenew?>')">
```

Comment: Stupid undo function doesn't work on a webpage(CTRL-Z). It undo more than last action. Here is correction to my text, so it is more understandable: Now my problem: I am running the AJAX code by onbeforeunload. When page is about to unload a popup-box shall appear with the message of unfinished.php(xmlhttp.responseText;) But the box will not trigger with my AJAX code inside.

Comment: No big mystery; `unfinished` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself. Did like this:

```
function unfinished(album,img){
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
         e = e || window.event;
     var response = '';
     var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
             // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }else{
             // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
             response = xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","incl/unfinished.php?a=" + album + "&i=" + img,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
     // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
     if (e) {
         e.returnValue = response;
     }
         // For Safari
     return response;
}
}
```

But now i have another problem... 1st of all the unload function works great, but I don't want it to trigger when the "Save crop" button is clicked. Any ideas how to do this?

Save button html:

Comment: <input type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save crop" id="save_thumb"/>